# Problemas con el archivo de enrutamiento

Tags: php, symfony3

hola a todos soy nueva usando Symfony, así que recurro a ustedes por su humilde ayuda ocurre que me encontré con una excepción:

> The routing file
>   "/home/desarrollo/my_project_name/src/AplicacionBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
>   contains unsupported keys for "aplicacion_homepage":
>   "aplicacion_primera". Expected one of: "resource", "type", "prefix",
>   "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults", "requirements",
>   "options", "condition" in
>   /home/desarrollo/my_project_name/src/AplicacionBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
>   (which is being imported from
>   "/home/desarrollo/my_project_name/app/config/routing.yml").

Esta es mi ruta:

```
aplicacion_homepage:
    path:     /index
    defaults: { _controller: AplicacionBundle:Default:index }


    aplicacion_primera:
    path:     /primera/{usuario}
    defaults: { _controller: AplicacionBundle:Default:primera}
```

Este mi controlador:

```
<?php

namespace AplicacionBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('AplicacionBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }


      public function primeraAction($usuario)
    {
        return $this->render('AplicacionBundle:Default:primera.html.twig',
 array('usuario'=>$usuario) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aplica una sangría correcta a tu fichero YML:

```
aplicacion_homepage:
  path:     /index
  defaults: { _controller: AplicacionBundle:Default:index }


aplicacion_primera:
  path:     /primera/{usuario}
  defaults: { _controller: AplicacionBundle:Default:primera}
```

Fíjate que aplicación_homepage y aplicacion_primera están a la misma altura. Para más información, busca documentación sobre el formato YML.